# How to insert DD MON YYYY format value into a date column in a snowflake table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My csv file has a date column having values in DD MON YYYY format eg: 28 Nov 2022.
When i tried inserting it into a date column(datatype= DATE) it is showing the below error. I have also tried using TO_DATE , TO_VARCHAR but getting the same error.

Kindly help me to resolve this.

> Error: Date '28 Nov 2022' is not recognized

I want to insert the value in the same format (DD MON YYYY) into a column of date data type ,without changing the format i.e '28 Nov 2022'.

Comment: Removed conflicting / irrelevant tags. Please tag your question with the right database product.

Comment: Date format in most databases are standard and `yyyy-mm-dd` [logical and universally understandable, and therefore processable] so convert your text date formay to that format before storing it

Comment: Please include the SQL you are using.

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: Hi how are you loading the file into Snowflake, are you using File format and a Stage to load or directly loading the file into a table ?

Comment: Load it up as `varchar` and cast it appropriate date type later. You can do that either as part of `copy into table` command or via `create or replace table` afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was reading documentation (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-datetime.html#date) and i read: "DATE accepts dates in the most common forms (YYYY-MM-DD, DD-MON-YYYY, etc.)."

So i think the format you are trying to write is a no-supported date format.
you can:

1. format your date in a supported date format before write field in db.
2. write in a varchar datatype field, but in this case you'll lose all tools on date type.

I don't see other ways!